# New Rspec 3 way to stub model (Rails 4.2/Rspec 3.1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

On one Rspec test (which works fine), I have a deprecation warning

> Using `stub` from rspec-mocks' old `:should` syntax without explicitly enabling the syntax is deprecated. Use the new `:expect` syntax or explicitly enable `:should` instead.

How should I change this test to be compliant with Rspec 3?

I am testing that the field company name exists/is not empty, then I have to validate presence of the company phone number field. I used to use 'stub' but it does not work properly and I'd like to move to the new Rspec 3 way.

/spec/models/company_spec.rb

```
describe "test on company name" do
  context "test" do
    before { subject.stub(:company_name?) { true } }
    it { is_expected.to validate_presence_of(:company_phone_number) }
  end 
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be like this:

```
describe "test on company name" do

  context "test" do
    before { allow(subject).to receive(:company_name?).and_return(true) }

    ...
  end 
end
```

Answer (score 2):

To stub a method under RSpec 3 use `allow/receive`:

```
allow(subject).to receive(:company_name?).and_return(true)
```

If you would to set an expectation that will fail if `company_name?` is never called:

```
expect(subject).to receive(:company_name?).and_return(true)
```